# Cannot see input in "Screen" application

Tags: bluetooth

I have succesfully paired and connected an Arduino to my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop via an HC05 bluetooth module. I can send data to the Arduino using the terminal opened with `sudo screen /dev/rfcomm0 9600` I know the Arduino is receiving the data because I have programmed a LED to switch on and of when a '1' or a '0' is received.

The problem I have is that I cannot see the input in the terminal opened with `sudo screen /dev/rfcomm0 9600`. The commands reach the Arduino but the terminal remains black with a blinking underscore character in the top left position. The blinking underscore character remains in the top left posion no matter what I input. How can I get to see the input in this screen?

Edit: I have tried `/usr/bin/screen` with 18.04 under both Wayland and X. And tried it with other serial ports,Edit:  for instance `sudo /usr/bin/screen /dev/ttyS0`. The result is always a black screen that passes on data but doesn't show what it is sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a part-solution that satisfies my requirements. Instead of `screen` I use `minicom`. At first `minicom` has exactly the same problem but you can switch local echo on with Control-A then E after which you can see what data you are sending.

According to the man page you should be able to turn `screen` local echo on with  `sudo /usr/bin/screen /dev/rfcomm0 echo` but I haven't been able to get that to work. I will now stick with the minicom solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before you upload your sketch, make sure your have the right port, if your not sure check it with `ll /dev/tty*` it will appears like `/dev/ttyUSBx` or `/dev/ttyACMx` and change it as read-write with follow `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0`. and then upload your sketch.

To use a `screen` package, don't used as `sudo` cause the package not your owned, try without `sudo`.

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

For kill the screen type with keyboard key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

For more information see `man screen`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I try to open `screen` without sudo I get the warning [screen is terminating]. But I have found a solution to my problem with minicom which I will post.

Comment: @SteveInBavaria cause you still have screen running process, kill it and run again

Answer (score -1):

## Screen is another command

Try using the full path to the command, like `/usr/bin/screen`

To see the conflicts, type in `whereis screen`

Comment: /usr/bin/screen has exactly the same problem as screen. Probably because it is exactly the same program. I don't know what you are getting at regarding "conflicts".

Comment: There is a program called `screen` in `/usr/bin` that does not do what you are asking. Try `sudo apt remove screen` and reinstall the Arduino version.

Comment: What is the name of the Arduino version of "screen"? How do I differentiate it in Apt with the "screen" that is already installed in /usr/bin. And why should I need an Arduino version of a common utility?

Comment: Screen might not be the program you are looking for. Use the command in the answers at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux